# Работа скрипта при разном размере экрана

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте. Есть скрипт:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0){
        $('.header').css({"background-color":"white"});
    }
    else {
        $('.header').css({"background-color":"transparent"});
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0){
        $('.link').css({"color":"#515769"});
    }
    else {
        $('.link').css({"color":"white"});
    }
});
```

Нужно что бы он, при ширине экрана <= 768px не менял цвет бэкграунда, а оставлял его белым.

Comment: Отличный пример здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306933/how-to-detect-window-size-and-then-do-something-with-jquery-switch-statement

Comment: А вы не могли бы применить этой к моему скрипту, у меня ничего не получилось?